# Export and import KDE custom shortcuts?

Tags: kde4, desktop-shortcuts

It is possible for the global shortcuts in the dedicated GUI.

[image]

Is it possible for the custom shortcuts too?

A similar option as above is not present in the KDE4 GUI for custom shortcuts.

[image]

But I imagine there must be some file to back-up.

Comment: check the file `~/.kde/share/config/kglobalshortcutsrc`  there are different sections, and the `[khotkeys]` one might be what you are searching for. It should then just be a matter of changing said file to your likings.

Comment: @Fiximan - it looks like the custom keys can be saved as groups; see my answer for details; but you should post comment as an answer or even better edit mine to add yours, so then I'll have a more complete answer to set as definitive. I have found all my custom actions as you said in `~/.kde/share/config/kglobalshortcutsrc`. If you prefer I can edit my answer myself and just give credit to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom shortcuts seem not to be saved as an overall scheme, but as separate groups of shortcuts.

In the Custom Shortcuts window select Edit - New group, if you don't have one or more already.

[image]

Check to enable the group and then drag&drop the shortcuts you already have onto the group.

To save a group, right click on it and export:

[image]